# LabVIEW: How to pass the reference of the event object as well as the indicator's reference to the callback

Tags: events, callback, labview

I am trying to figure out a way to display a variable updated by .NET while LabVIEW's callback is called by .NET.

I have a simple application called "EventGenerator" written with .NET and what it does is that upon calling Start() it automatically increments a variable called IncrementingValue. Once Stop() is called it stops to increment.

Every time the variable is updated the property is changed (eg. PropertyChanged)

I want to use a callback to display on the indicator. So I registered a callback for the variable and I want to display the updated value on the indicator.

Is there a way to pass the reference of the event object as well as the indicator's reference to the callback so that the callback can update the value ?

.NET code

```
namespace EventGenerator 
{
    public ref class GeneratorClass : System::ComponentModel::INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    // Public functions
    public:
        GeneratorClass();
        ~GeneratorClass() { };
        void Start();
        void Stop();
        void Reset();

    private:
        void EventThreadHandler();

    // INotifyPropertyChagned
    public:
        void OnPropertyChanged(System::String^ info);
        virtual event System::ComponentModel::PropertyChangedEventHandler^ PropertyChanged;

    // Properties
    public:
        property int IncrementingValue
        {
        internal:
            void set(int value)
            {
                m_incrementingValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IncrementingValue");
            }
        public:
            int get() 
            {
                return m_incrementingValue;
            }
        }
```

**LabVIEW code**

Test: Front panel
[image]
Ok button event
[image]
Stop button event
[image]
Reset button event
[image]
Callback front panel
[image]
Callback 
[image]